# Limit macro to active sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have a worksheet within a multi-worksheet workbook `Workbook1` which contains some VBA code that executes when certain calculated cells change in value. All works well.  However, if that workbook is active and I open another workbook `Workbook2` unrelated to `Workbook1`, it seems the VBA code for `Workbook1` attempts to execute and I get a message box with Runtime Error:

> "9: Subscript out of range"

message.  As If the code for Workbook1 is being executed.  If I press the DEBUG button on the runtime error, I see the code for `workbook1`.

I need to limit the execution of the specific VBA code to `Workbook1`, `FEED_ANALYSIS` Sheet.

Included is the `Workbook1` code which is attached to the `FEED_ANALYSIS` sheet.

Thank you in advance.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    Dim Cost_Per_day
    Dim COST_kg
    Dim COST_GROSS_kg
    Dim AVG_SALES_PRICE
    Dim COST_NET_PURCHASE
    Dim PROFIT_GROSS
    Dim PROFIT_NET
    Dim PROFIT_NET_X
    Dim Flag_set

    Dim dtmTime As Date
    Dim Rw As Long

'If Critical Cells change, move contents to Log sheet

    Dim Xrg As Range
    Set Xrg = Range("E5:I11")
    If Not Intersect(Xrg, Range("E5:I11 ")) Is Nothing Then
        dtmTime = Now()
        Cost_Per_day = Worksheets("FEED_ANALYSIS").Range("E7").Value
        COST_kg = Worksheets("FEED_ANALYSIS").Range("F7").Value
        COST_GROSS_kg = Worksheets("FEED_ANALYSIS").Range("G7").Value
        AVG_SALES_PRICE = Worksheets("FEED_ANALYSIS").Range("I5").Value
        COST_NET_PURCHASE = Worksheets("FEED_ANALYSIS").Range("G11").Value
        PROFIT_GROSS = Worksheets("FEED_ANALYSIS").Range("I7").Value
        PROFIT_NET = Worksheets("FEED_ANALYSIS").Range("I8").Value
        PROFIT_NET_X = Worksheets("FEED_ANALYSIS").Range("I9").Value

        Rw = Sheets("LOG").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

        With Sheets("LOG")
            datcomp = .Cells(Rw - 1, 1)

       ' if the previous entry date is the same as the current date, do not create the entries... one entry per day

            If Year(datcomp) = Year(dtmTime) And Month(datcomp) = Month(dtmTime) And Day(datcomp) = Day(dtmTime) Then GoTo NoUpd

            .Cells(Rw, 1) = dtmTime
            .Cells(Rw, 2) = Cost_Per_day
            .Cells(Rw, 3) = COST_kg
            .Cells(Rw, 4) = COST_GROSS_kg
            .Cells(Rw, 5) = AVG_SALES_PRICE
            .Cells(Rw, 6) = COST_NET_PURCHASE
            .Cells(Rw, 7) = PROFIT_GROSS
            .Cells(Rw, 8) = PROFIT_NET
            .Cells(Rw, 9) = PROFIT_NET_X
            .Cells(Rw, 11) = .Cells(Rw - 1, 1)
NoUpd:
        End With   
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: You need to add the workbook qualification in front of your worksheet references. e.g.Workbooks("WorkbookName").WorkSheets("FEED_ANALYSIS").etc

Comment: And you need to make sure that you also qualify all methods that implicitly refer to the active worksheet (e.g.  Range("E5:I11"), Sheets("LOG")

Answer (score 0):

When starting the macros the first time, have it get the workbook name in a global variable. Then use that variable in qualifying the wokbook tou want to work in. If you now open another workbook, the macro will work on the correct wokbook:

```
Dim gWorkBookName As String

Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    '...
    If (gWorkBookName = "") Then
        gWorkBookName= ActiveWorkbook.Name
    End If
    '...
    With Workbooks(gWorkBookName)
        Cost_Per_day = .Worksheets("FEED_ANALYSIS").Range("E7").Value
        '...
    End With
    '...
End Sub
```